# How to change tornado post header and add into header new data?

Tags: python, python-2.7, tornado

I have handler which handles post request and returns some JSON to client, before I return I need to validate input data, if data doesn't pass validation I need to put in header ( I don't know how to modify header and put additional key) that it isn't pass validation flag under key VALIDATION or anything else. 
How to change tornado post header and add into header this data ?

```
def post(self):
    data = tornado.escape.json_decode(self.request.body)
    key = data.get('key', None)

    # here if key is not in db and did not pass validation I should add VALIDATION key value False to header and send back to client 

    result = fetch_data_for(key)        
    self.write(json.dumps(result))
    self.flush()
```

Comment: You should provide some code as an example

Comment: @PyNEwbie I added code where I have a problem

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`RequestHandler` has `set_header` and `add_header` methods: http://www.tornadoweb.org/en/stable/web.html#tornado.web.RequestHandler.set_header

```
#!/usr/bin/python
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

import tornado.httpserver
import tornado.ioloop
import tornado.options
import tornado.web

from tornado.options import define, options
define("port", default=8000, help="run on the given port", type=int)

class IndexHandler(tornado.web.RequestHandler):
    def post(self):
        data = tornado.escape.json_decode(self.request.body)
        key = data.get('key', None)

        # result = fetch_data_for(key)        
        result = "ok\n"

        self.add_header('validation', 'value')
        self.write(result)      

if __name__ == "__main__":
    tornado.options.parse_command_line()
    app = tornado.web.Application(handlers=[(r"/", IndexHandler)])
    http_server = tornado.httpserver.HTTPServer(app)
    http_server.listen(options.port)
    tornado.ioloop.IOLoop.instance().start()
```

Output:

```
$ curl -v "Accept: application/json" -H "Content-type: application/json" -X POST -d '{"key":"..."}'  http://localhost:8000
* getaddrinfo(3) failed for Accept:80
* Couldn't resolve host 'Accept'
* Closing connection #0
curl: (6) Couldn't resolve host 'Accept'
* About to connect() to localhost port 8000 (#0)
*   Trying 127.0.0.1... connected
> POST / HTTP/1.1
> User-Agent: curl/7.22.0 (i686-pc-linux-gnu) libcurl/7.22.0 OpenSSL/1.0.1 zlib/1.2.3.4 libidn/1.23 librtmp/2.3
> Host: localhost:8000
> Accept: */*
> Content-type: application/json
> Content-Length: 13
> 
* upload completely sent off: 13out of 13 bytes
< HTTP/1.1 200 OK
< Date: Sun, 09 Jun 2013 16:49:40 GMT
< Content-Length: 3
< Validation: value
< Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8
< Server: TornadoServer/3.0.1
< 
ok
* Connection #0 to host localhost left intact
* Closing connection #0
```